# Input field data is visible to the user but apparently invisible to Chrome Dev Tools? How can I get at it?

Tags: dom, browser, google-chrome-devtools, cypress

Since I know Cypress, I offered to help a friend screen scrape data out of a legacy system for which he no longer has database access, but I seem to be at a dead-end.

The PHP code fills the form fields somehow, and I can cut'n paste from them into an editor but, when I try to automate that, the `input` field's innerText is always empty strings.  I can use Dev Tools to search the DOM and find the text of the field labels, but searching for the input field text turns up nothing.

Is there really **no** way to get at that data?

How can Chrome be unable to find data that it is actually displaying?

Is this some kind of security barrier?

Comment: You will need to show the relevant HTML and Javascript. Maybe it is a Java applet, or a Flash applet or something that does not exist in HTML (and thus, not for the Chrome DevTools).

Comment: From what I can see, it is PHP & jQuery  (https://datatables.net/)

Comment: ... an `<input>` field has no `innerText` attribute. If you want to get at the field value, use the `value` attribute?!